# js for newest chat message order

Tags: javascript

in my chat extension for phpBB, i use ajax for the js with a little jquery mixed in. i'm setting it up for users to select if they want the newest messages at the top or the bottom in accordance to their setting in their user control panel. the php side of it is done and works well but the js is still adding the new message at the top, ignoring the sort order in the php.

in the php. note that the sort order is set with this line
`ORDER BY c.message_id ' . ($this->user->data['user_ajax_chat_messages_down'] ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');`
i can't post the php in this post as the body is limited to 30000 characters. so i will post it if needed.

here is the js that does all the work

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());
    if (expires) {
        expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    }
    var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));
    document.cookie = name + '=' + escape(value) +
            ((expires) ? ';expires=' + expires_date.toGMTString() : '') + //expires.toGMTString()
            ((path) ? ';path=' + path : '') +
            ((domain) ? ';domain=' + domain : '') +
            ((secure) ? ';secure' : '');
}

//******************************************************************************************
// This functions reads & returns the cookie value of the specified cookie (by cookie name)
//******************************************************************************************
function getCookie(name) {
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
    var len = start + name.length + 1;
    if ((!start) && (name !== document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
        return null;
    }
    if (start === -1)
        return null;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', len);
    if (end === -1)
        end = document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}

function deletecookie(name)
{
    var cookie_date = new Date( );  // current date & time
    cookie_date.setTime(cookie_date.getTime() - 1);
    document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
    location.reload(true);
}

var form_name = 'postform';
var text_name = 'message';
var fieldname = 'chat';
var xmlHttp = http_object();
var type = 'receive';
var d = new Date();
var post_time = d.getTime();
var interval = setInterval('handle_send("read", last_id);', read_interval);
var name = getCookie(cookie_name);
var blkopen = '';
var blkclose = '';

if (chatbbcodetrue && name !== null && name !== 'null') {

    blkopen = name;
    blkclose = '[/color2]';
}

function handle_send(mode, f)
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 || xmlHttp.readyState === 0)
    {
        indicator_switch('on');
        type = 'receive';
        param = 'mode=' + mode;
        param += '&last_id=' + last_id;
        param += '&last_time=' + last_time;
        param += '&last_post=' + post_time;
        param += '&read_interval=' + read_interval;

        if (mode === 'add' && document.postform.message.value !== '')
        {
            type = 'send';
            for (var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++)
            {
                elem = f.elements[i];
                param += '&' + elem.name + '=' + blkopen + "" + encodeURIComponent(elem.value) + blkclose;
            }
            document.postform.message.value = '';
        } else if (mode === 'add' && document.postform.message.value === '')
        {
            alert(chat_empty);
            return false;
        } else if (mode === 'edit')
        {
            var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
            type = 'edit';
            mode += '/' + f;
            param = '&submit=1&message=' + message;
        } else if (mode === 'delete')
        {
            var parent = document.getElementById('chat');
            var child = document.getElementById('p' + f);
            parent.removeChild(child);
            type = 'delete';
            param += '&chat_id=' + f;
        } else if (mode === 'quotemessage')
        {
            type = 'quotemessage';
            param += '&chat_id=' + f;
        }

        xmlHttp.open('POST', query_url + '/' + mode, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handle_return;
        xmlHttp.send(param);
    }
}

function handle_return()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4)
    {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            results = xmlHttp.responseText.split('--!--');

            if (type === 'quotemessage') {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $text = document.getElementById('message').value;
                    document.getElementById('message').value = $text + results[0];
                    document.getElementById("message").focus();
                    $('#chat').find('.username, .username-coloured').attr('title', chat_username_title);
                }
            } else if (type === 'edit') {
                jQuery(function($) {

                    'use strict';

                    var opener = window.opener;
                    if (opener) {
                        $(opener.document).find('#p' + last_id).replaceWith(results[0]);
                    }

                    var popup = window.self;
                    popup.opener = window.self;
                    popup.close();
                    $('#chat').find('.username, .username-coloured').attr('title', chat_username_title);
                });
            } else if (type !== 'delete') {
                if (results[1])
                {
                    if (last_id === 0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = results[0];
                    } else
                    {
                        document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = results[0] + document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML;
                    }
                    last_id = results[1];
                    if (results[2])
                    {
                        document.getElementById('whois_online').innerHTML = results[2];
                        last_time = results[3];
                        if (results[4] !== read_interval)
                        {
                            read_interval = results[4];
                            window.clearInterval(interval);
                            interval = setInterval('handle_send("read", last_id);', read_interval * 1000);
                            document.getElementById('update_seconds').innerHTML = read_interval;
                        }

                    }
                    $('#chat').find('.username, .username-coloured').attr('title', chat_username_title);
                }
            } else if (type == 'delete') {
                var parent = document.getElementById('chat');
                var child = document.getElementById('p' + results[0]);
                if (child) parent.removeChild(child);
            }
            indicator_switch('off');
        } else {
            if (type == 'receive') {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
            handle_error(xmlHttp.status, xmlHttp.statusText, type);
        }
    }
}

function handle_error(http_status, status_text, type) {
    var error_text = status_text;

    if (http_status == 403) {
        if (type == 'send') {
            error_text = chat_error_post;
        } else if (type == 'delete') {
            error_text = chat_error_del;
        } else {
            error_text = chat_error_view;
        }
    }
    $('#chat-text').after('<div class="error">' + error_text +'</div>');
}

function delete_post(chatid)
{
    document.getElementById('p' + chatid).style.display = 'none';
    handle_send('delete', chatid);
}

function chatquote(chatid)
{
    handle_send('quotemessage', chatid);
}

function indicator_switch(mode)
{
    if (document.getElementById("act_indicator"))
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("act_indicator");
        if (img.style.visibility === "hidden" && mode === 'on')
        {
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else if (mode === 'off')
        {
            img.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("check_indicator"))
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("check_indicator");
        if (img.style.visibility === "hidden" && mode === 'off')
        {
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else if (mode === 'on')
        {
            img.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}

function http_object()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e)
            {
                document.getElementById('p_status').innerHTML = (ie_no_ajax);
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        document.getElementById('p_status').innerHTML = (upgrade_browser);
    }
}

//START:Whatever
function addText(instext)
{
    var mess = document.getElementById('message');
    //IE support
    if (document.selection)
    {
        mess.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = instext;
        document.message.focus();
    }
    //MOZILLA/NETSCAPE support
    else if (mess.selectionStart || mess.selectionStart === "0")
    {
        var startPos = mess.selectionStart;
        var endPos = mess.selectionEnd;
        var chaine = mess.value;
        mess.value = chaine.substring(0, startPos) + instext + chaine.substring(endPos, chaine.length);
        mess.selectionStart = startPos + instext.length;
        mess.selectionEnd = endPos + instext.length;
        mess.focus();
    } else
    {
        mess.value += instext;
        mess.focus();
    }
}
//END;Whatever

function parseColor(color) {
    var arr=[]; color.replace(/[\d+\.]+/g, function(v) { arr.push(parseFloat(v)); });
    return {
        hex: "#" + arr.slice(0, 3).map(toHex).join(""),
        opacity: arr.length == 4 ? arr[3] : 1
    };
}
function toHex(int) {
    var hex = int.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

jQuery(function($) {

    'use strict';

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $("#smilies").click(function () {
            $("#chat_smilies").toggle(600);
        });
        $("#bbcodes").click(function () {
            $("#chat_bbcodes").toggle(600);
        });
        $("#chat_bbpalette").click(function () {
            $("#chat_colour_palette").toggle(600);
        });
    });

    var $chat_edit = $('#chat_edit');
    $chat_edit.find('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        handle_send('edit', $chat_edit.find('input[name=chat_id]').val());
    });

    $('#chat').find('.username, .username-coloured').attr('title', chat_username_title);

    $('#chat').on('click', '.username, .username-coloured', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $(this).text(),
            user_colour = ($(this).hasClass('username-coloured')) ? parseColor($(this).css('color')).hex : false;

        if (user_colour) {
            insert_text('[color=' + user_colour + '][b]@' + username + '[/b][/color], ');
        } else {
            insert_text('[b]@' + username + '[/b], ');
        }
    });
});
```

what needs to be changed to accomplish what i'm trying to do? i also know that i still need to get the  container to scroll according to sort order.
if more info is needed, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it all sorted with the following part

````
                        var content = chat.innerHTML;
                        chat.innerHTML = isDown ? (content + results[0]) : (results[0] + content);

                        // Scroll to bottom
                        if (isDown) {
                            var chatContainer = document.querySelector('.shout-body');
                            chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
                        }```
````